# Container Apache + Nodejs, como criar?

Tags: node.js, docker

Subi um container com **Apache** + **PHP**, porém, preciso utilizar o **Laravel-mix**, logo necessito do **npm** e **nodejs**. Tudo funciona ok, entretanto, em um determinado momento vi que o container reiniciou, isso pode está relacionado a minha abordagem de por tudo junto conforme abaixo?

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && a2enmod rewrite && apt-get install -y curl unzip git npm && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs

...
```

Alguma recomendação no contexto do cenário acima?

Comment: Qual é o log de quando ele reinicia? E o status de encerramento do container? Lembre-se que quando tem mais de um processo rodando por padrão não é enviado um _SIGTERM_ para outro, ficando o container não integro.

Comment: Não cheguei a observar o log. No caso desta imagem, como posso usar um supervisor para permitir a execução do apache e nodejs?

Comment: Tem um exemplo bem completo usando ele aqui: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/